# Logitech MX Master Buttons don't work

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

so I just received a MX Master and I am having some troubles with it. 
The only buttons which work, are left- and rightclick and the wheel.
The Back/Forward Buttons, the horizontal Wheel and the top button don't do anything when pressed.

Just to test them, in Logitech Options, I set all of them to open the Calculator. If I press down the scroll wheel, the calculator does open, but the other buttons dont do anything. Also the scroll wheel can't be changed to ratchet mode, I couldn't figure out how.

I checked different versions of the Logitech options software, but it's not working.
Any similar experience? Or is it simply broken? I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The broken ratchet switch may be an indication of a bad unit. The Windows 10 driver will recognize the forward and back buttons and horizontal scroll in a web browser.

Comment: I have read about the wheel issues this product has. But the fact that I can assign anything to the other buttons and they just don't do anything is another issue.

Comment: To add this, I obviously tried the forward and back buttons and the horizontal wheel, in a web browser of course. None of them seem to have any function.
To further investigate, I opened a Game and in the settings tried to bind some functions to it (A game which has the "press button to bind" function). Nothing happens when you click the mentioned buttons.